# VNC connection to Ubuntu EC2

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, vnc, vnc-server, vnc-viewer

I've been trying to get a VNC connection to my Ubuntu instance installed at EC2.

This is what I have done so far :-

- Install x11vnc and run it as `x11vnc -create`. I used the create flag as I wasn't sure if I believed an xserver wouldn't be running and would have to be created. I got the following output mentioning that "The VNC Desktop is , Port=5903".
- I edited the security groups to allow incoming connections to port 5903.
- I tried connecting to the VNC desktop from my Mac using "Chicken of the VNC" at the public dns and port 5903 but it says `connect() failed`.

What am I doing wrong? Am I binding to the wrong interface? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default port for x11vnc server is 5900, which can be changed.The VNC server will listen for connections from a VNC viewer on TCP port 5900+N, where N is the display port number (by default zero). Just make sure you open the correct port, so that you can get access. Also correctly configure other settings. Follow the links to setup the server:

http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Ubuntu:Maverick#VNC

http://judsonsnotes.com/notes/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=706:set-up-a-vnc-server-in-ubuntu&catid=37:tech-notes&Itemid=59